# Write to elastic search from inside Django view

Tags: django, python-2.7, elasticsearch

I'm trying to sync a local SQLite database-entry with an elastic search index.

Here is the view:

```
def sync_model(request, model_id):
    data = create_json(model_id)
    es = Elasticsearch(hosts=[{'host': 'my_host', 'port': '9200'}])
    res = es.index(index='my_index', doc_type='my_doctype', id=model_id, body=data)
    return redirect('/')
```

And error at line 4:

> ConnectionError(: Failed to establish a new connection: getaddrinfo() argument 2 must be integer or string) caused by: NewConnectionError(: Failed to establish a new connection: getaddrinfo() argument 2 must be integer or string)

The put to elastic search works normally. Am I missing knowledge that doesn't allow this behavior inside Django? Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Driver expects port to be specified as integer. Checkout docs [example](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/)

```
es = Elasticsearch(
   hosts=[{'host': host, 'port': 443}],
   http_auth=awsauth,
   use_ssl=True,
   verify_certs=True,
   connection_class=RequestsHttpConnection
)
```

Comment: Wow that's embarrassing. Thank you